# wp7 listbox binding from json

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, listbox

Hi everybody i have a little problem i can't bind the data in the listbox ,if someone could tell me what's the problem plz

i parse my data and i get all what i want from the json below

```
{
maj: true,
data: [
{
c: 2,
t: 0,
r: [
168,
"La rentrée Auchan",
0,
"2012-08-15 00:00:00",
"2012-08-21 00:00:00",
56,
"VL"
]
},
....
```

i parse the data that i want with no problem,i get all the data that i want everything works but i don't know how to bind it in this case . NB:the json result is in the e.result

```
  var obj = App.Current as App;
            // obj.R2= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(e.Result).data.Where(d => d.t == 0).SelectMany(d => d.r.Take(2));

            JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
            JArray arr = (JArray)jobject["data"];
            List<JsonC> apps = new List<JsonC>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
            {
                apps.Add(new JsonC { t = (int)arr[i]["t"], r = (JArray)arr[i]["r"] });
            }
            List<int> itList = new List<int>();
            List<int> Number = new List<int>();
            List<string> Name = new List<string>();
            List<string> stList = new List<string>();
            //listClients.ItemsSource = apps.Where(ap => ap.t == 0);
            foreach (var el in apps.Where(ap => ap.t == 0))
            {
                itList.Add((int)el.r[0]);
                Name.Add((string)el.r[1]);
                Number.Add((int)el.r[5]);
                stList.Add((string)el.r[6]);
            }

            obj.R1 = itList;
            obj.R2 = Number;
            obj.R3 = Name;
            obj.R4 = stList;
```

now i've tried to do bind obj.R3 in the texblock  but it doesn't work any help ?

```
<ListBox Height="512"  Margin="0,-2,6,0" Name="listClients" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="listImage_Loaded">

                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="150" ItemWidth="150"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding obj.R3}" x:Name="Textblock1" Foreground="Black" Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the Datacontext for the ListBox from the code-behind itself.

```
listClients.ItemsSource = obj.R3;
```

and

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" .../>
```